# print the area of the circle with function in c++ - all declared double but integer result, why?

Tags: c++, function

I'm studying c++ and i have to do this exercise where i have to calculate and print out the area of a circle with the ray in input by the user.
This seems work but the result it's not a double but a int type. why?
Thanks in advance.
Here the code:

```
#include <iostream>

double area_f(double raggio_f); //prototype

using namespace std;

    int main(){
        double raggio, area;

        cout << "inserire il raggio: " << endl;
        cin >> raggio;

        area = area_f(raggio);
        cout << area;
        return 0;
    }

    double area_f(double raggio_f){
        double risultato;
        risultato=raggio_f*raggio_f*3,14;
        return (risultato);
    }
```

Comment: Read about the [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator).

Comment: Your code should look like this 
`risultato=raggio_f*raggio_f*3,42;`

Answer (score 7):

The statement:

```
risultato=raggio_f*raggio_f*3,14;
```

Is using C++'s comma operator, which discards the first result, and returns the second (14). Use 3.14 instead.

Answer (score 3):

```
risultato=raggio_f*raggio_f*3,14;
```

There is a typo, `3,14` vs `3.14`. It's valid C++ ([comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator)), but the result won't be what you expected.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use fullstop notation for decimals.:

`risultato=raggio_f*raggio_f*3.14;`

The reason it is an integer is because `3` is an integer and it is ignoring the `14`

Answer (score 0):

3.14 in the following statement below as opposed to 3,14

risultato=raggio_f*raggio_f*3,14;

comma operator exists in c++ and hence gives a different result rather than providing a syntax error.